# should I re-initialize my optimizer and my scheduler before I try to fine tune my neural network on the different dataset?

Tags: neural-networks, train

I am doing NLP, and I have this block of Transformer body that was already trained on dataset A.
Now I am interested in fine tuning this same Transformer on a new dataset B.

In my Python code, should I re-initialize my optimizer and my scheduler before I try to fine tune my neural network on the different dataset?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reinitializing the optimizer would probably reset momentum information. Either way, it would probably not make a massive difference.

Learning rate schedule is important -- fine-tuning is typically done with a much smaller learning rate, so as not to "mess up" the already carefully learned weights. You should probably use a completely different learning rate schedule for fine-tuning.

Comment: Hello, Thank you very much for your reply. So say I am using the linear schedular with warm up for both pre-training and fine-tuning. If so, would it be better to not initialize the linear schedular for fine tuning, since we want our learning rate to be small for fine-tuning? Thank you,

Comment: yeah, that sounds right